# Understanding this proof regarding maximum ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> **Prove:** Let $R$ be a commutative associative ring with $1$ and $M \triangleleft R$. The factor-ring $R/M$ is a field iff $M$ is the max ideal in $R$.
>
> ($\implies$) Let $R/M$ be a field, then because Theorem:[Commutative, associative ring $F$ with $1$  is a field iff $F$ does not have any right ideals other than $0$], $R/M$ does not have any right ideals.
>
> **But because of the natural homomorphism $\pi: R\to R/M$, every ideal $A$ in $R$ that contains $M$  must coincide with $M$ or with $R$, because $R/A\triangleleft R/M$, so $M$ is the max ideal in $R$.**

I highlighted what is unclear to me, this is directly taken from my textbook.

Comment: You haven't made it clear **what** you find unclear about that section. For example, do you understand the definition of the homomorphism $\pi$?

Comment: (Also, please do not use MathJax in that way again. Markdown is the right way to format text on this site.)

Comment: I understand the definition $\pi : x (\in R) \to x + M $

Comment: R/A $\triangleleft$  R/M is unclear to the part of the sentence that precedes it is as well because they are logically related. Then from there on, to the end, the conclusion is unclear too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part you highlighted follows from the correspondence theorem for rings, which says there is a bijective correspondence between the ideals of $R$ containing $M$ and the ideals of $R/M$.

You want to show that an ideal of $R$ containing $M$ has to equal either $R$ or $M$.

Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ containing $M$. Then $I$ corresponds to some ideal $I/M$ of $R/M$.

But since $R/M$ is a field, the only ideals it has are the zero ideal $0/M$ and the ideal that is the whole ring $R/M$: the zero ideal $0/M$ corresponds to $M$, and the ideal $R/M$ corresponds to $R$. This means that $I$ is either $M$ or $R$.

Comment: +1. Also known as the "lattice" theorem, or the "fourth isomorphism theorem".